# Creating duplicate leads via API calls

Tags: rest-api, leads, apexrest

I have a rest API endpoint in Salesforce which accepts a payload from my application. On reception of the first request with a given email, it creates a lead. On subsequent requests, it finds the lead and updates the lead with extra information in the payload. My problem is that if a user quickly moves through the process (like have most of the fields filled and they just click the next button, it is a wizard-like interface), I have to call the API in quick succession. While the first call is creating the lead, the second call searches for a lead with a given email (which is not created yet) and starts the call to create a new lead. In the meantime, the first call has finished creating the lead as well. Now I have 2 leads instead of one :(

Is there a way on the Salesforce side I can handle this? Can't change the way requests land, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FOR UPDATE` SOQL keyword in Apex to require row locks for the leads you're querying. This ensures that the lead query matching by email will wait for any other in-flight records. This will ensure that you're not creating duplicates, even if the records are inserted simultaneously between two API calls.

```
Lead[] existingLead = [SELECT Email FROM Lead WHERE Email = :incomingEmail FOR UPDATE];
```

Comment: wonderful, that inflight thing is what is messing it. I'll try this and report back!

Comment: well, we tried (at least dev told me) and it is not working :(

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Maybe some Duplicate Rules, then? That is 100% reliable, but you'll have to deal with the errors.

Comment: That sounds good plan I've email and another unique piece of information and I don't want to have duplicate lead with email+uniquething combo! Voila, seems like a way out. On error go and query the existing lead.